# How to implement filter in ADF table

Tags: filter, oracle-adf

In my web page I need to show a table with a list of proposals. The table data comes from an ArrayList of proposals. The data will be shown in a af:table and the list is generated at runtime not pulled directly from a database.
I have enabled filtering of the table but that doesn't do the trick. When entering a value in the "filter box" the table reloads but is still containing all rows. Searching the internet for tutorials on how to implement filtering didn't bring me any closer.

Can any of you describe which steps I need to take?
If you have links for tutorials regarding this topic they are very welcome.

Please ask if you need more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the filter facet inside the af:column and add af:inputText that corresponds to the enter character to filter your arrayList, it'll be tedious job but it can be done in the end.

Check this url http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/16-custom-table-filter-169145.pdf page 10 for some information about how to use the filter facet